# Hash password in Swift application

Tags: encryption, passwords, hash, scrypt

For security purposes I will encrypt some data, including the user password in my application.

My colleagues have chosen scrypt hashing algorithm, for a 64 bytes length, with a fixed seed, then converted to hex.

Hashing "**A12345678Z**" leads to: `25fac84a1cc3a8f6706848d1016cfe7e9d3631691306dcacae68c11c7b54f0bf89e7a7fc51f7fcc19671775acb21c8d928c4c96bb66d915925de58b8b36ab251`

Seed is “**HeanpyftAkWilfUd**”.

On server, they are using this implementation : https://github.com/ricmoo/pyscrypt

Example:

```
scrypt.hash(“A12345678Z", “HeanpyftAkWilfUd").encode('hex’)
```

->

```
25fac84a1cc3a8f6706848d1016cfe7e9d3631691306dcacae68c11c7b54f0bf89e7a7fc51f7fcc19671775acb21c8d928c4c96bb66d915925de58b8b36ab251
```

My question is how to do that in Swift? What library to use and if it possible - show me sample code, that will lead hashing "**A12345678Z**" to exactly this:

```
25fac84a1cc3a8f6706848d1016cfe7e9d3631691306dcacae68c11c7b54f0bf89e7a7fc51f7fcc19671775acb21c8d928c4c96bb66d915925de58b8b36ab251
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Swift-Sodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/swift-sodium). It's a Swift interface for the [Sodium crypto library](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/).

Here's an example from the README.md

```
let sodium = Sodium()!
let password = "Correct Horse Battery Staple".toData()!
let hashedStr = sodium.pwHash.scrypt.str(password,
opsLimit: sodium.pwHash.scrypt.OpsLimitInteractive,
memLimit: sodium.pwHash.scrypt.MemLimitInteractive)!

if sodium.pwHash.scrypt.strVerify(hashStr, passwd: password) == false {
   // Password doesn't match the given hash string
}
```

Comment: Okay, but I can not achieve the same result as theirs. If I use your example, I get a different hex value. Any ideas if it is possible to achieve the exact same result?